# How do i remove the rows in this csv file that contain certain strings

Tags: r, rstudio

My file that i am reading in is very large and a certain string of words always appear multiple times throughout the file. I just need to have it go through the file and delete every row containing those specific strings/NAs.

I have used the grep function to try to get rid of the strings, but it only gets rid of the first string to appear and none of the rest of the same strings.

```
RAO <- readr::read_csv(file = "RateAddOnsExcel.csv")

RAO$...4 <- NULL
RAO$...5 <- NULL
RAO$Quarter. <- NULL
names(RAO)[1:13] = c("ProviderName","AIMNumber", "ChainName", 
"RateEffectiveDate", "ComponentTotal", 
                 "VentAddOn", "QualityAddOn", 
"SpecialCareUnitAddOn", "AssessmentAddOn", 
                 "SelectedExpenditureAddOn", "RateReduction", 
"CaseMixRate", "CaseMixAssessment")
RAO$AIMNumber <- NULL
RAO$ChainName <- NULL
names(RAO)[1:13] = c("ProviderName","AIMNumber", "ChainName", 
"RateEffectiveDate", "ComponentTotal", 
                 "VentAddOn", "QualityAddOn", 
"SpecialCareUnitAddOn", "AssessmentAddOn", 
                 "SelectedExpenditureAddOn", "RateReduction", 
"CaseMixRate", "CaseMixAssessment")

RAO <- RAO[-which(apply(RAO, 1, function(x)all(is.na(x)))),]

View(RAO)
remove.list <- paste(c("Myers", "Provider", "NA", "JJ"), collapse = 
'|') 
RAO %>% filter(!grepl(remove.list, RAO$ProviderName)) 
RAO %>% filter(!str_detect(RAO$ProviderName, remove.list))
```

I would like to get rid of those specific strings i put in there.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of an input you have and what you want to achieve. What would be helpful if you provide an output of head(RAO) function or str(RAO) or if you are using `dplyr` package glimpse(RAO). And then explain what you would like to get as a result. For example: "I would like to get rid of all rows, where column <column name>  has a duplicate or a missing value".

Comment: I would like it to run through my whole file and if the column A for example starts with Myers, Provider or NA it will delete the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# simulate some data
set.seed(12345)
RAO <- data.frame(A = sample(c("Myers", "Provider", "NA", "JJ", "Stack","Overflow"), 50, replace=T),
              B = rnorm(50) )
head(RAO)
#          A          B
# 1    Stack  1.8050975
# 2 Overflow -0.4816474
# 3    Stack  0.6203798
# 4 Overflow  0.6121235
# 5       NA -0.1623110
# 6    Myers  0.8118732

# Remove rows where column A is one of Myers,Provider or NA
RAO %>% filter( !grepl ("Myers|Provider|NA", A))
#           A           B
# 1     Stack  1.80509752
# 2  Overflow -0.48164736
# 3     Stack  0.62037980
# 4  Overflow  0.61212349
# 5        JJ  2.04919034
# 6     Stack  1.63244564
```

Or if values in column A contain more than a single word and you want to remove those rows, where the value starts with one of these 3 words, you can add "^" symbol to the regular expression in `grepl` function: `grepl ("^Myers|^Provider|^NA", A)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! do you happen to know a way to graph data points using multiple variables. For example i have Min <- min(a) and max <- max(a) and median <- median(a) i want to be able to select a value and show how it compares to the min max and median

Comment: @RyanUsesR If the above answers  the question in this post, please "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.  As for your other question  - it would be hard to answer in a comment. You need to post a new question. A short answer - I would draw a boxplot or similar and place the "selected value" on top of the boxplot.